# Switching server host between PCs in a client-server system

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server, client

I have 4 PCs and a basic client-server system with sockets. One of them starts as the server, and the others as clients. I would like to change the host of the server depending on a certain event and have the other PCs automatically join the new server. How would this be possible?

The system is working correctly, but I haven't found a way to change the server PC.

Comment: The first thing that springs to mind is to have an additional multicast socket on each box and then you can broadcast a message informing of change of address